# Python file sort

Tags: python, import, operating-system

So i wrote this to help me sort files in a bunch of different folders, it works by taking the first file from each folder and creating a folder for it then the 2nd file from each folder and does the same and so on, but when ever I run the code nothing happens can someone help.

```
import os, sys

path = "\Users\mac\Desktop\soliddd sort\dir"
fdir = os.listdir(path)
f = len(fdir[0])

array = [[] for i in xrange(f)]

def setArray(c, i, j):
    array[j][i] = c[j]

def chooseFile(j):
    for i in fdir:
        setArray(fdir[i], i, j)

def makedir(f, fdir):
    for i in f:
        folder = r"\Users\mac\Desktop\soliddd sort\dir"+str(i)
        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)

        for j in fdir:
            with open(os.path.join(folder, array[i][j], 'wb')) as temp:
                temp.write(buff)
            folder.close()

def main():
    for j in f:
        chooseFile(j)
    makedir(f, fdir)
```

Comment: first off, before you continue to test, SANDBOX this .. create some dummy dirs -- do not run this on stuff you care about until you know it will work

Comment: second, single-letter variable names make it incredibly difficult to figure out what you're trying to do, and may help you resolve your issue faster

Comment: third, use import shutil, and use shutil.move(src, dst) to move files around

Answer (score 0):

A tiny example on how you can go about sorting files into folders, as I couldn't understand why you were randomly selecting files from different locations. This example gets all the file names, and then lets you select a common filename to sort into a new folder

```
def sort_files(base_dir="C:\sorted_files")
    import os, shutil
    folder_list     =   [
                            'folder_path_a',
                            'folder_path_b',
                        ]
    file_list       =   []
    for folder in folder_list:
        file_list.extend([os.path.join(folder, file_name) for file_name in os.listdir(folder)])
    key             = raw_input("Group files with <text> in the filename: ")
    matching_files  = [ file_name for file_name in file_list if key in file_name ]
    for file_name in matching_files:
        shutil.move(file_name, os.path.join(os.path.join(base_dir,key), os.path.basename(file_name)))
```